# Android Toolbar Menu Gone

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-gallery

what's up? I'm having a hard time with my toolbar menu which is going missing whenever I pick a photo from gallery:

[image]

Here is my code on "PostDetailFragment", the one where the toolbar menu is going missing:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

to your OnCreate().  Also, not entirely sure you need the `menu.clear()`